# How do I get the photos on the internal memory of my Instax Mini EVO?

Tags: file-transfer, fujifilm-instax

I took photos on my Instax Mini EVO using its internal memory and I'm trying to transfer them to a microSD card. But when I put in my microSD card, it doesn’t show the photos I have in the internal memory.